# Start Jenkins with -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3" options

Tags: linux, svn, jenkins, tomcat6

I have problem regarding Jenkins svn sheckout. I found possible solution for my issue which says "start jenkins with -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3" " Problem is I don't know how to do it. Jenkins is .war file on tomcat6, running on centos.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this to CATALINA_OPTS in your tomcat start script. Depending on how your tomcat is installed, this could be a script in init.d or catalina.sh somewhere. I personally use a wrapper script to start Tomcat with Jenkins as a war.

Reference:
https://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS you should add your custom JAVA options at

> /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

Put your params at the line:

> JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true **-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols='SSLv3'**"

And restart the service

> service jenkins restart

This is the best practice, you can modify the catalina scripts or the /etc/init.d/jenkins script but exists some risk to lose the changes after jenkins upgrades.